# Curve_fit RuntimeWarning message in Scipy python

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit my data with curve_fit. However, I get this warning message.

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log

I searched that this means there's negative value in log. However, I don't have negative values in my data. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
def fit(x,a,b):
    return a*np.log(b*x+1)
q = [0., 4.698, 9.396, 13.148, 18.792, 22.416, 26.296, 30.176, 34.056]
r = [0., 1.50755518, 3.53050467, 6.5067685, 9.8676480, 12.8481805, 14.6121058, 15.5656062, 16.69052756]
fit_log_param, _ = curve_fit(fit, xdata=q, ydata=r)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> this means there's negative value in log

That is correct.

The reason that happens is because curve_fit tries altering various parameters, and calculates chi^2 or some other metric to try and find a meaning. Varying these parameters may cause these kind of warnings. This could happen, for example, when b gets negative: `b*x+1` may become a negative value as inupt for the log.

The resulting metric will often be infinite or NaN and be considered worse than any metric before, so these parameter values will quickly be discarded as being "not good". They shouldn't hamper the fitting, but will slow it down (if only slightly).

If you start `curve_fit` with some starting parameters close to what you expect, you often have

- a quicker result (less iterations)
- no warning messages
- a result at all (some bad starting parameters may fail to find a good optimum)

So provide some good starting parameters. That is probably good practice every time you use `curve_fit`, with any type of function you're trying to fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fit(x,a,b):
    return a*np.log(b*x+1)
q = [0., 4.698, 9.396, 13.148, 18.792, 22.416, 26.296, 30.176, 34.056]
r = [0., 1.50755518, 3.53050467, 6.5067685, 9.8676480, 12.8481805, 14.6121058, 15.5656062, 16.69052756]
fit_log_param, _ = curve_fit(fit, xdata=q, ydata=r, bounds=[(-2, 0), (500, 100)])
```

The log means in the search process of curve_fit, b*x+1 may be negative, so you can limit the bound of the parameters with the param bounds to avoid this.